# display status from user who i follow

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ask, and I really need the answer.

here I have 3 tables in one database.

1 # users
- id_user (int)
- username (text)

2 # status_update
- id_status (int)
- id_user (int)
- username (text)
- status (text)

3 # follow
- id_user (int)
- id_user_follow (int)
- username (text)
- username_follow (text)

the question is, how to display the status of the user that I follow .. and do not display the status of the user that I not follow. ?? .. using php and mysql, please, need help.

## NEW QUESTION

im sorry, im still dont understand, this is my real table

Please help, I still do not understand the answer in [my previous post][1], here I have 3 tables.

```
1 # profile
- id_user
- username
- email

2 # picture
- id_picture
- id_user
- the title

3 # subscribe
- id_user_a
- Id_user_b (people who subscribe at user_a)
- date
```

now the question is, how to display the title picture in people who subscribe only, and does not display the title picture in people who do not subscribe,

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: There's no need for username in 'status_update' table. Also, there's no need for username and username_follow in the 'follow' table. I know that doesn't answer your question but you should fix that before you do anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should fix your database structure. Here's mine suggestion:

```
users - id (int), username (varchar)
status_updates - id (int), users_id (int), status (text)
follow - users_id, following_users_id
```

Please note, that you shouldn't save users username in each table, save it only in `users` table. Also, username should be `varchar` type.

And here is your query in fixed database:

```
SELECT u.username, s.status
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN follow f ON u.id = f.following_users_id
LEFT JOIN status_updates s ON u.id = s.user_id
WHERE f.user_id = USER_ID
```

Comment: how to order from new status to old status??

Comment: If you don't have date of status, you should add `ORDER BY s.id DESC` at the end of query. Note, that `s.id` should be `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: hmm sorru but that code just only show my following update and my own update not showed, plzz helpme once again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.username, s.status 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN follow f ON (u.id_user = f.id_user_follow) 
LEFT JOIN status_update s ON (u.id = s.user_id) 
WHERE f.id_user = USER_ID;
```

You should look in to normalising your tables, you do not need to replicate the username in every table.

Answer (score 0):

SQL: `SELECT status FORM status_update AS s LEFT JOIN follow AS f ON s.id_user = f.id_user_follow WHERE f.id_user = 'YOUR_ID' LIMIT 0,5`

than in PHP it depends on whether you've got a connection to Db allready or not..
as the draft you can start with `var_dump($query->result());`